# Removing duplicates and printing the string in specific output

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, duplicates

Here's the output I want to get:

```
Please enter sentence: Hello Python!
' ' 1
'!' 1
'H' 1
'P' 1
'e' 1
'h' 1
'l' 2
'n' 1
'o' 2
't' 1
'y' 1
[' ', '!', 'H', 'P', 'e', 'h', 'l', 'n', 'o', 't', 'y']
```

This is the code I tried:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def rmdup(str1):
    return "".join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(str1))
str = input("Please enter sentence: ")
sorted_str = sorted(str)
str1 = []
for i in range(len(str)):
    j = sorted_str.count(sorted-str[i])
    str1 = list(rmdup(str1))
    print(repr(sorted_str) + '\t' + repr(j))
print(str1)
```

and here's the output I get:

```
Please enter sentence: Hello Python!
' ' 1
'!' 1
'H' 1
'P' 1
'e' 1
'h' 1
'l' 2
'l' 2
'n' 1
'o' 2
'o' 2
't' 1
'y' 1
[' ', '!', 'H', 'P', 'e', 'h', 'l', 'n', 'o', 't', 'y']
```

Comment: you cannot have `-` as part of a variable name. An underscore `_` on the other hand is valid.
Call the variable `sorted_str` instead of `sorted-str`. But you should have got a syntax error for that.

Please post next time also the error that you encounter. and if our program executes, then post not only the expected output, but also the output, that you got

Comment: great you got an answer that helped you.

I made an edit request to make your code working.

Please next time try to be careful to post exactly the code, that caused problems.

I'm quite sure, that above code with `sorted-str` instead of `sorted_str` didn't work at all and did not output the result you're suggesting in your questions.

You make everybody's live much easier if the code you post, can be copied and pasted and  allows to reproduce your issue.

Enjoy SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `collections.Counter` container.

```
from collections import Counter

sentence = input('Please enter a sentence: ')
counter = Counter(sentence)
for key, value in counter.items():
    print("'{}' {}".format(key, value))

print([key for key in counter.keys()])
```